# Is it possible to trigger an AWS Lambda function directly from CloudWatch alarm?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sqs

Currently, for triggering a lambda function in response to a CloudWatch alarm, I need to route the alarm via SNS, like this:

```
AWS CloudWatch Alarm --> Send to a topic in SNS --> SNS topic triggers the lambda function
```

**So, is there a way I can do it directly, without SNS in the middle?**  [Reason: Less touch points and a bit of cost optimization].

CloudWatch events trigger lambda but there is no way I can trigger alarms via it. The only options available in CloudWatch events for SQS are:

> [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800976/how-to-connect-a-cloudwatch-alarm-to-a-lambda-function

Comment: It is possible to trigger Lambda function from CloudWatch alarm
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/12/amazon-cloudwatch-alarms-lambda-change-action/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible. The the offcial A[WS Lambda documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html) says it support CloudWatch **Events**, but no mention of CloudWatch **Alarms** (and [CW Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html) != [CW Alarms](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html))

What you are currently doing, sending the alarms on a SNS and using listening on a topic seems the way to go. In fact, CloudWatch Alarms only outputs to SNS so far.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to trigger Lambda function from CloudWatch alarm, by using EventBridge https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-and-eventbridge.html